# 30 Day distance between dates in datetime64[ns] column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data of the following form:

```
6460  2001-07-24 00:00:00    67.5      75.1   75.9   71.0   75.2    81.8
6490  2001-06-24 00:00:00    68.4      74.9   76.1   70.9   75.5    82.7
6520  2001-05-25 00:00:00    69.6      74.7   76.3   70.8   75.5    83.2
6550  2001-04-25 00:00:00    69.2      74.6   76.1   70.6   75.0    83.1
6580  2001-03-26 00:00:00    69.1      74.4   75.9   70.5   74.3    82.8
6610  2001-02-24 00:00:00    69.0      74.0   75.3   69.8   73.8    81.9
6640  2001-01-25 00:00:00    68.9      73.9   74.6   69.7   73.5    80.0
6670  2000-12-26 00:00:00    69.0      73.5   75.0   69.5   72.6    81.8
6700  2000-11-26 00:00:00    69.8      73.2   75.1   69.5   72.0    82.7
6730  2000-10-27 00:00:00    70.3      73.1   75.0   69.4   71.3    82.6
6760  2000-09-27 00:00:00    69.4      73.0   74.8   69.4   71.0    82.3
6790  2000-08-28 00:00:00    69.6      72.8   74.6   69.2   70.7    81.9
6820  2000-07-29 00:00:00    67.8      72.9   74.4   69.1   70.6    81.8
```

I want all the dates to have a 30 day difference between each other. I know how to add a specific day or month to a `datetime` object with something like

```
ndfd = ndf['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
ndfd = ndfd.apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=15))
```

But this does not take into account the difference in days from month to month.

How can I ensure there is a consistent step in days from month to month in my data, given that I am able to change the day as long as it remains on the same month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `date_range`:

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start=df['date'][0], periods=len(df), freq='30D')
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could change your date column like this:

```
import datetime

a = df.iloc[0,0]  # first date, assuming date col is first 
df['date'] = [a + datetime.timedelta(days=30 * i) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Comment: What is `a`, my `Date` column?

Comment: Sorry, it's the first date value - clarified that now

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so not sure it work as smooth as I thought it will =).

You can transform your first day into ordinal, add 30*i to it and then transform it back.

```
first_day=df.iloc[0]['date_column'].toordinal()
df['date']=(first_day+30*i for i in range(len(df))).fromordinal
```